# How do I hide the UITableViewCell border for a custom cell in a group tableview?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton, border

**What I am trying to do:** I want three buttons side-by-side in a tableviewcell just like in Contacts app.

**What I've done:** I have a custom tableviewcell with three uibuttons in it. I've set the background color of the tableviewcell to be transparent.

**What I can't figure out:** The tableviewcell border is still there! Everything looks great except for the border floating around the 3 buttons.

Am I doing this completely wrong? Or is there a simple way to remove/hide the border?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put these in a cell. Simply create a custom UIView that contains the three buttons, and use that view as your Table's footer:

```
[myTableView setTableFooterView:customUIViewWithButtons];
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

What about if I want my transparent cell in the middle?